# How to accumulate based on a condition and group classes together in Drools

Tags: drools

```
rule "STANDARD - set available application"
salience(2)
when
    accumulate ( Application( $priority : priority, running == false), $highestPriority :         min( $priority ) )
then
    System.out.println("set app: "+$highestPriority );
end
```

My code is above.  My goal is to find Applications where running == false and get the highest priority of those applications (highest being lowest value) but this rule fires on all applications and ignores my condition. Thoughts???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use and accumulate pattern here. You can rewrite your rule to something like this:

```
rule "STANDARD - set available application"
salience(2)
when
    $highestPriorityApp: Application(running == false, $highestPriority : priority)
    not Application(running == false, priority < $highestPriority)
then
    System.out.println("set app: "+$highestPriorityApp );
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Haven't checked your alternative solution thoroughly, most probably it's the best solution for this problem. But per my understanding the code OP posted is correct use of accumulate pattern, so I got intrigued to know why it does not work. Got any clues?

Comment: How are you inserting your facts and firing your rules? Are you inserting all your facts and then firing the rules? or are you firing the rules after each insertion?

Comment: if I understood correctly, you're saying that the accumulate function posted by OP is correct, but in case he/she is not passing all the facts to WM at the same time and firing the rules with all facts, it cannot work. That makes sense.

Comment: That is correct (although I wasn't aware of the possibility to bind a variable to min() in the accumulate). If he/she is doing a fireAllRules after each insertion, he/she may have multiple activations and executions of that rule (depending whether the priority of the inserted Applications are in decreasing order or not).